# Save firestore SERVER_TIMESTAMP without nanoseconds

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, fastapi

I am saving the createTime as a `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` and it stores the date with date and time in nanoseconds. That is more precision than required and I would like to instead just store it in a format which could be serialized by fastapi in Python - preferably datetime format only. Right now, I get the following error `TypeError: Type is not JSON serializable: DatetimeWithNanoseconds`.

I can fix the above error using JsonEncoder but I would like to achieve this without json Encoder.

Is there a way I can go about it?

Comment: Answer on your specific question below. But consider showing the code of how you currently *read* the timestamp and that generates the error message, as there *may* be room for improvement there that prevents the need for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to specify the precision of Firestore's server timestamp. You will either have to handle the over-precision when you read the data back into your code, or you could use a Cloud Function that triggers on the initial write and then adds a lower precision value based on what Firestore wrote.